# Two CSS issues in Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I am running Thesis Theme 1.8.5 on Wordpress and here is my site www.texashomeloanpro.com . Unfortunately, there is some CSS showing up in Safari that I am trying to remove. More specifically, I am trying to remove the following from appearing in Safari:

- the blue borders around my "new sidebars"
- the single bullet-point that shows up to the left of my red
  "feature box."

I have researched this issue thoroughly and I have tried several CSS solutions but I just can't get these issues resolved.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0):

```
li.widget{
    list-style: none;
}
.custom #new-sidebars .widget_box{
    border: none;
}
```